# I need to classify by categories without mixing the data of different columns

Tags: r, function, classification, aggregate, categories

I have the following dataset:

```
Year Company Product Sales
2017  X       A       10
2017  Y       A       20
2017  Z       B       20 
2017  X       B       10
2018  X       B       20
2018  Y       B       30
2018  X       A       10 
2018  Z       A       10
```

I want to obtain the following summary:

```
Year Product Sales
2017 A       30
     B       30
2018 A       50 
     B       20
```

and also the following summary:

```
Year Company Sales
2017  X      20
      Y      20 
      Z      20
2018  X      50
      Y      10 
      Z      10
```

Is there any way to do it without using loops?

I know I could do something with the function aggregate, but I don't know how to proceed with it without mixing the data of company, product and year. For example, I get the total sales of product A and B, but it's mixing the sales of both years instead of giving A and B in 2017, and separated in 2018.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your dataframe is called df:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Year', 'Product')['Sales'].sum()
df2 = df.groupby('Year', 'Company')['Sales'].sum()
```

I believe this would help you create your two summary dataframes without mixing anything :) !